# Получить подстроку, которая ограниченна с двух сторон определёнными символами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пишу телеграмм бота на Python telebot. Необходимо распарсить текстовую часть сообщения, где указано название места и его адрес.
Сообщение такого вида:

```
/add\n
Name: Дом\n
Address: Адрес моего дома
```

Мне необходимо получить подстроки "Дом" и "Адрес моего дома".
Желательно решить эту задачу с помощью регулярных выражений(модуль re).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой регуляркой можно это реализовать.

Comment: В сообщении явно прописан символ `\n` или вы так перевод строки обозначили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^(Name|Address):\s(.+)$
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/Tuofee/1

Сгенерированный код:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(Name|Address):\s(.+)$"

test_str = ("/add\n"
    "Name: Дом\n"
    "Address: Адрес моего дома")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```